# How can I set the vertex color iGraph based on a column in a data frame?

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to set the color of vertices in iGraph based on a extra column in the data frame.  I didn't see a question like this in my search. although I thought that last time and ended up asking a duplicate question.  My data looks like this:

```
Vertex1     Vertex2    Type
Chat        Forms      Other
Specials    Chat       Info
Form Sent   Linkout    Lead
Home        Chat       Home
```

I am trying to set the value of the Vertex based on the content of the type column.  Here is the code I am using:

```
V(paths.g)$Type=as.character(VDP_Path5$Type[match(V(paths.g)$Type,VDP_Path5$Node1)])
V(paths.g)$color=V(paths.g)$Type
V(paths.g)$color=gsub("Lead","forest",V(paths.g)$color)
V(paths.g)$color=gsub("Vehicle","leaf",V(paths.g)$color)
V(paths.g)$color=gsub("Home","gold",V(paths.g)$color)
V(paths.g)$color=gsub("Other","silver",V(paths.g)$color)

plot(paths.g, edge.width=VDP_Path5$weight,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold)
```

When I run the plot all the vertices are the default cyan color.

Thank you

Comment: What do the `gsub` functions do?

Comment: gsub is a pattern matching and replacement function in R.  The general usage is `gsub(pattern, replacement, x)`

Comment: Sorry, can you help me understand what they do in this case?

Comment: They replace the "Type" field with the corresponding color.  "forest", "leaf", etc are color codes.

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this:

```
edges <- c(1,2, 3,4, 2,4, 1,3, 1,5)
g <- make_graph(edges, directed=FALSE)
plot(g, vertex.color=1:5)
```

Adding color as a vertex attribute is not necessary, but you can do like `vertex.color=V(g)$color` when plotting.  There are also more straightforward ways to transform text to a particular colors (I would go for a named color vector).

Please make your data/code reproducible if you want more precise suggestions :-)

Comment: I am trying to set the vertices to several different colors to aid in distinguishing activities.  I doubt you want to see the entire list of 167 edges.  The data provided is representative of the full list in a data frame.

Comment: I mean something like `dput(head(data))`.  It is easy to use dput output for testing.

Comment: This does not answer my question.  I also tried a nested ifelse statement, but it does not seem to make a difference either.


`V(paths.g)$color <- ifelse(V(paths.g)$Type=='Lead', "green4", 
                    ifelse(V(paths.g)$Type=='Vehicle', "greenyellow", 
                    ifelse(V(paths.g)$Type=='Home', "gold", "grey70")))`